# Pandas Days after Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Hello I have a Dataframe like this in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-10-01', '2022-10-04', '2022-10-17'],
                   'value': [100, 110, 95]})
```

How can I subtract the date from a default value?

I've tried it like this

```
'2022-10-20' - df['date']
```

but got an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I want to calculate the values 19, 16, 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `datetime` object to calculate the difference and then get the number of days with the `.dt` accessor

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
(datetime(2022, 10, 20) - pd.to_datetime(df["date"])).dt.days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) and [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
(pd.Timestamp('2022-10-20') - pd.to_datetime(df['date'])).dt.days
```

Or:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).rsub(pd.Timestamp('2022-10-20')).dt.days
```